# Sum of n numbers result is wrong in Scala

Tags: scala

I am reading comma-separated numbers from a text file from and performing addition of all numbers in a file - but the sum I'm getting is wrong.

## Input file

```
1,2,3
```

## Source code

```
val file=Source.fromFile("D:/scala/test.txt")
 val f1=file.foldLeft(0)((a,b)=>a+b)
 println(f1)
```

## Output

```
238
```

I can perform addition on an Array and it works fine, but I can't get the correct answer when reading the data from a file.

Comment: What is the type of file?

Comment: Its a text File

Comment: some times 
1,2,
3,
4,
5
if my file contains data like this its just displaying as it is not doing any operation

Comment: So if it's a text file, what are you folding over? [Hint: there are 5 of them in your "inputfile" example.]

Comment: I am trying to perform addition I need output like sum of all numbers in a file

Comment: Yes, but that's a text file and those aren't numbers.

Comment: I tried
 file.sum
file.reduce(_+_)
but Not giving what I expected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `Source` is an `Iterator[Char]`, so your `foldLeft` is operating on `Char`s. When you add two Chars with `+`, you're adding their decimal values.

Your source is reading *every* character from that file, *including* the commas. If you look at an ASCII chart, you'll see that the decimal value of a comma (i.e. `,`) is 44, and 1, 2, and 3 are 49, 50 and 51 respectively.

This gives us `44 + 44 + 49 + 50 + 51 = 238`, which is the result you're seeing.

What you really want is probably something like this:

1. Read your file to a string
2. Split that string on commas
3. Convert each of the result strings to an int
4. Sum the resulting integers

Which can be written as

```
Source.fromFile("D:/scala/test.txt").mkString.split(',').map(_.toInt).sum
```

or

```
Source.fromFile("D:/scala/test.txt").mkString.split(',').map(_.trim.toInt).sum
```

Note that `toInt` will throw if the input can't be parsed to an int.

Comment: Wow great answer Thanks

Comment: Ya Its working fine

But When I have file Like this 

1,2,
3,
4,
5

Comment: first Line 1,2,
second line 3,4,5
3rd Line 6,7,

Comment: Sounds like you need to `trim` whitespace before trying to parse to int.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "
4"

Answer (score 3):

`Source.fromFile("D:/scala/test.txt")` will return the `Char` sequence.

like `1,2,3` it will return `Char`: `1,2,3` and in `ASCII Number`, it should be **Int Numbers**:

```
 49,44,50,44,51
```

so for your `fold` is summing this **Int** sequence.and result is `238`